# Rails: Accessing Enum Value in View Layer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, enums

I am having trouble accessing an enum value from the view layer in Rails.

I have an ActiveRecord model named `Rule` which has an enum `operation` defined:

```
class Rule < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum operation: [:says, :contains]
end
```

I have passed a rule to my view and I am trying to access the operation field. The object returns `nil`, despite having a value.

```
= rule.inspect             #=> #<Rule id: 2, operation: 1>
= rule.operation           #=> Nil
= rule.operation.class     #=> NilClass
```

When I attempt to access the operations field from my console, it works just fine.

```
rule.inspect             #=> #<Rule id: 2, operation: 1>
rule.operation           #=> "contains"
```

I verified that `operation` is not a ruby/rails keyword. Is there some trick to getting enums to show up in the view layer?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I tried renaming the column to 'op' and that did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was caused when I clobbered the hash which defined the enum. I did this in order to provide options for a select tag.

```
@operations = RowRule.operations
# alter @operations here
```

I solved this by cloning the hash:

```
@rule_operations = RowRule.operations.clone
# alter @operations here
```